# How can I check if permissions are not more permissible than a certain level in multiple files?

Tags: linux, bash, centos

I want to make sure /etc/file1 and /etc/file2 are not more permissible than 644.  I have tried

```
if [[ `stat /etc/file1 --format=%a | cut -b 1` -le "6" -a `stat /etc/file2 --format=%a|cut -b 1` -le 6 ]]; then echo "good"; else echo "bad"; fi;
```

but I get "bash: syntax error in conditional expression
bash: syntax error near `-a'"

My plan with the above is just to repeat it three times (one for each byte of the permission).

I am also not sure if either test is working correctly because I cannot get them to run outside of the test.

Comment: "More permissible than 666 "just means "has an execute bit set" doesn't it?

Comment: I guess so. The actual number I need is 644 though.  I'll change it to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming "more permissive" means any extra permission that file1 or file2 has above and beyond 644.

Some examples are:

- 664 is more permissive as "group" can now write to the file.
- 700 is more permissive than 644 because even though "group" and "other" have less permissions, the "owner" has more
- 640 is less permissive as "other" can no longer read, it could before

This basically means at least one extra bit is set in file1 or file2 compared to 644.  Therefore, if you AND 644 and the file1 permission, the result is the bits common to both.

Say file1 is 640. 644 AND 640 will result in 640. Because the result is the same as file1's permissions, you know that file1's permissions are at least a subset of 644.

Say file2 is 700.  644 AND 700 will result in 600.  600 is not the same as 700, so there must be bits set (i.e. different permissions) in file2 that 644 does not have.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

BASEPERM=644

for FILE in /etc/file1 /etc/file2; do
        COMPARISON=$(stat -c '%a' "$FILE")
        RESULT=$(printf '%o' $((8#$BASEPERM & 8#$COMPARISON))) # AND the permissions
        if [[ $RESULT -eq $COMPARISON ]]; then # If the result is the same as the file's permissions...
                echo "Not more permissive" # ...then you know the file has no more permissions than the base permission
        else
                echo "More permissive"
        fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a much simpler way:

<strike>maxperms="666"</strike>

```
if [ `stat /etc/profile --format=%a` -gt $maxperms ]
then
   echo "TOO PERMISSIVE"
else
   echo "FINE"
fi
```

Oops, second cut:

```
for d in `stat test.txt --format=0%a | fold -w1`
do 
   if [ $d -gt "6" ] 
   then 
      echo "TOO PERMISSIVE"
      exit
   else
      echo "FINE"
   fi
done
```

Comment: The problem with that is 077 is less than 666, but is more permissive.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by "more permissible than 666" you just means "has an execute bit set" then I believe

```
find $path -perm /111
```

does what you want.

Extending to `644` permissions makes that find command something like:

```
find $path -perm /100 -o \( -perm /044 -a -perm /033 \)
```

I think.

I feel like there is likely a clever way to get from the desired permissions to the find patterns but I'd have to give that more thought.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare them bit by bit:

```
#!/bin/bash

function has_good_perm {
    local FILE STAT X
    for FILE; do
        STAT=$(exec stat -c '%a' "$FILE")
        X=${STAT:0:1}
        (( X & 1 )) && return 1               ## False if first number has executable bit e.g. 7, 5, 1
        X=${STAT:1:1}
        (( (X & 1) || (X & 2) )) && return 1  ## False if second number has executable bit or writable bit e.g. 7, 6, 5, 3, 1
        X=${STAT:2:1}
        (( (X & 1) || (X & 2) )) && return 1
    done
    return 0
}

if has_good_perm /etc/file1 /etc/file2; then
    echo "All files are good!"
else
    echo "Something's bad."
fi
```

Or

```
function has_good_perm {
    local STAT X
    STAT=$(exec stat -c '%a' "$1")
    X=${STAT:0:1}
    (( X & 1 )) && return 1
    X=${STAT:1:1}
    (( (X & 1) || (X & 2) )) && return 1
    X=${STAT:2:1}
    (( (X & 1) || (X & 2) )) && return 1
    return 0
}

for FILE in /etc/file1 /etc/file2; do
    if has_good_perm "$FILE"; then
        echo "Good file: $FILE"
    else
        echo "Bad file: $FILE"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need "more permissible than 644", you in fact search if *any* bits in 133<sub>8</sub> (i.e.: 644<sub>8</sub> XOR 777<sub>8</sub>) is set.

Then, according to `man find`:

> ```
>    -perm /mode
>           **Any** of the permission bits mode are set for the file.   Symbolic
>           modes  are  accepted in this form.  You must specify `u', `g' or
>           `o' if you use a symbolic mode.  See the  EXAMPLES  section  for
>           some  illustrative  examples.  If no permission bits in mode are
>           set, this test matches any file (the idea here is to be  consis‐
>           tent with the behaviour of -perm -000).
> ```

So, that would probably do the job:

```
find $path -perm /133
```

Or more precisely concerning you specific need:

```
BADFILES=$(find /etc/file1 /etc/file2 -perm /133)
if [ -n "$BADFILES" ]
then
    echo 'Bad!' 1>&2
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Without checking all answers, xor alone will not tell which is more permissive. Comparing one bit at a time might be too complex.
Below is my solution in go (translate carefully to bash).
We just want to collect bits that are "on" in the actual file permissions where those bits are "off" in "644"
Note the there is no natural-order in linux permissions since one file can have group execute permissions and other can have write permissions. Their permissions are simply different or alternatively we can say that each file is more permissive then the other (for different type of permissions)
func main() {
lessRestrictiveExample()
}

```
// // we should detect cases where actualPermissions has a permission bit "on" is "off" in the requiredPermissions.
// required | actual   | res
//     0    |     0    |  0
//     0    |     1    |  1    <== we care about this case. actual has more
//     1    |     0    |  0
//     1    |     1    |  0
func lessRestrictiveExample() {

    zeroMaskForDontCare, _ := strconv.ParseUint("777", 8, 32)

    actualPerms, _ := strconv.ParseUint("643", 8, 32)
    requiredPerms, _ := strconv.ParseUint("644", 8, 32)

    result := (^requiredPerms) & actualPerms

    result3OctalDigits := result & zeroMaskForDontCare

    fmt.Printf("actualPerms (Octal): %o\n", actualPerms)
    fmt.Printf("actualPerms (Binary): %b\n", actualPerms)
    fmt.Printf("requiredPerms (Octal): %o\n", requiredPerms)
    fmt.Printf("requiredPerms (Binary): %b\n", requiredPerms)
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Printf("zeroMaskForDontCare (Octal): %o\n", zeroMaskForDontCare)
    fmt.Printf("zeroMaskForDontCare (Binary): %b\n", zeroMaskForDontCare)
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Printf("^requiredPerms (Octal): %o\n", ^requiredPerms)
    fmt.Printf("^requiredPerms (Binary): %b\n", ^requiredPerms)
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Printf("Result (Octal): %o\n", result3OctalDigits)
    fmt.Printf("Result (Binary): %b\n", result3OctalDigits)

    fmt.Printf("-- Is %o LESS restrictive then %o? --\n ###   %v  ###\n", actualPerms, requiredPerms, result3OctalDigits != 0)
}
```

This is the output:

```
actualPerms (Octal): 643
actualPerms (Binary): 110100011
requiredPerms (Octal): 644
requiredPerms (Binary): 110100100

zeroMaskForDontCare (Octal): 777
zeroMaskForDontCare (Binary): 111111111

^requiredPerms (Octal): 1777777777777777777133
^requiredPerms (Binary): 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111001011011

Result (Octal): 3
Result (Binary): 11
-- Is 643 LESS restrictive then 644? --
###   true  ###
```